# .each function running correctly once but then says 'undefined is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I'm writing a simple function which gets the URL of a post and then returns the number of times it has been shared on Twitter. There are multiple posts on a page so I need the function to run for each post. Below are the relevant functions (note that I'm using RequireJS).

```
function twitterCount($target) {

            $article = $target.closest($('article')),

            articleHREF = $target.parent().parent().attr('data-href');
            APIURL = 'https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json';

            //Get count and set it as the inner HTML of .count
            $.getJSON(APIURL + "?callback=?&url=" + articleHREF, function(data) {
                $target.find('.count').html(data.count);
            });
        }

getTwitterCount: function() {
            $twitterLink.each(function() {
                $target = $(this);
                $target.function(twitterCount($target));
            });
        }
```

The function is running correctly once and giving me the number of times the first post on the page has been liked, but then ceases to work and spits out **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** in the console. I'm struggling to see why it would run the once but then not work for every other post. The error points to the following line...

```
$target.function(twitterCount($target));
```

The HTML where the output should be is below

```
<ul class="share-options" data-href="http://localhost/test-post/">
                <li><a class="twitter" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    Twitter <span class="count twitter-count"></span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a class="linkedin" href="javascript:void(0)">LinkedIn</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Please add the html and the error from the console.  Should get a line number that will help you know what the problem is

Comment: What is the line in question supposed to do? Is it just trying to pass `$target` to `twitterCount()`? Where do you define `$twitterLink`?

Comment: The script is relatively long so I didn't want to paste it all in. $twitterLink simply defines $('.twitter').

The line in question is supposed to pass the item that is currently being iterated over to the twitterCount function.

Comment: A little confused here, what do you want to do with ```$target.function(twitterCount($target));``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success by modifying your code a bit.

Main changes:

1. I changed the `.twitter` class reference to `.twitter-count` to match your HTML
2. I removed your `getTwitterLink` function and just performed the `each()` directly.
3. I replaced `$target.function(twitterCount($target))` with `twitterCount($target)`
   This was the big syntax error.

Other changes in code comments below.

```js
function twitterCount($target) {

    /* I simplified "parent().parent()" to "closest()" */
    articleHREF = $target.closest('ul').attr('data-href');
    APIURL = 'https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json';

    $.getJSON(APIURL + "?callback=?&url=" + articleHREF, function (data) {
        /* I changed ".twitter" to ".twitter-count" to match the class in your HTML */
        $target.find('.twitter-count').html(data.count);
    }).fail( function(d, textStatus, error) {
        /* I added this fail handler, just in case */
        console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: "+error)
    });
}

$twitterLink = $('a.twitter');

/* I removed the function here as it didn't seem necessary */
$twitterLink.each(function () {
    $target = $(this);
    /* Your function call here threw a syntax error.
       Replaced `$target.function(twitterCount($target))` with `twitterCount($target)` */
    twitterCount($target);
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cL9uT/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much showdev, this has resolved it. Like you said, it was bad syntax on my part around this line: $target.function(twitterCount($target)). The function just before the .each is used as part of RequireJS to run functions at particular times, so I have kept that in.